# convert matrix of checkboxes to edgelist of column names

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

beginning R programmer here! I'm working on some projects for work and i'm trying to familiarize myself with the functions of R. Background in python and C, and have been relying on for- and while-loops a lot. Now with R i notice i should avoid that, so i'm asking for some pointers to help with specific problems.

Right now i have a data.table that looks like this:

```
    +-------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
    | names |  Q1 - mike | Q1 - rebecca | Q1 - anna | Q2 - mike | Q2 - rebecca | Q2 - anna |
    +-------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
    | linda |            |    x         |    x      |    x      |              |           |
    | john  |  x         |              |    x      |           |              |   x       |
    | anna  |  x         |    x         |           |    x      |              |           |
    +-------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Representing people who have answered names of their friends as the answer to a question (e.g. "is this person your friend?", "Have you seen him last week?"). I need to change the shape of this table to an edgelist, like so:

```
    +-------+-----------+---------+
    | names |  question | answer  |
    +-------+-----------+---------+
    | linda |  Q1       | rebecca |
    | linda |  Q1       | anna    |
    | john  |  Q1       | mike    |
    | john  |  Q1       | anna    |
    | anna  |  Q1       | mike    |
    | anna  |  Q1       | rebecca |
    | linda |  Q2       | mike    |
    | john  |  Q2       | anna    |
    | anna  |  Q2       | mike    |
    +-------+-----------+---------+
```

I have seen the `reshape` function and i'm learning about it now. I'm wondering if there are other functions that could help here? Or what is the proper terminology to describe these types of matrices (so i can google in the future)?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `data.table::melt`:

```
melt(DT, id.vars="names")[value=="x"][, 
    c("qn","ans") := tstrsplit(variable, split=" - ")][]
```

output:

```
   names     variable value qn     ans
1:  john    Q1 - mike     x Q1    mike
2:  anna    Q1 - mike     x Q1    mike
3: linda Q1 - rebecca     x Q1 rebecca
4:  anna Q1 - rebecca     x Q1 rebecca
5: linda    Q1 - anna     x Q1    anna
6:  john    Q1 - anna     x Q1    anna
7: linda    Q2 - mike     x Q2    mike
8:  anna    Q2 - mike     x Q2    mike
9:  john    Q2 - anna     x Q2    anna
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("names |  Q1 - mike | Q1 - rebecca | Q1 - anna | Q2 - mike | Q2 - rebecca | Q2 - anna |
linda |            |    x         |    x      |    x      |              |           |
john  |  x         |              |    x      |           |              |   x       |
anna  |  x         |    x         |           |    x      |              |           |", colClasses="character")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can i ask a follow-up question? What if i want the melt function to be able to recognize any value as an answer, and not just "x"? If someone enters "b" instead of "x" i want to record that they wrote "b".

Comment: maybe `value!=""` like Ronak's answer?

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr` and `dplyr` using @chinsoon12's data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DT %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -names) %>%
  #gather(name, value, -names) %>% #In older version of tidyr
  filter(value != "") %>%
  separate(name, c("question", "answer"), sep = " - ") %>%
  select(-value)

#  names question answer 
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  
#1 linda Q1       rebecca
#2 linda Q1       anna   
#3 linda Q2       mike   
#4 john  Q1       mike   
#5 john  Q1       anna   
#6 john  Q2       anna   
#7 anna  Q1       mike   
#8 anna  Q1       rebecca
#9 anna  Q2       mike
```

Also a small variation to the above would be :

```
DT %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -names, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  separate(name, c("question", "answer"), sep = " - ") %>%
  select(-value)
```